# Proper way to shut down consumer

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

Say we have a simple pipeline:

```
set -eo pipefail;
echo 'foo' | cat
```

how does `cat` know when to exit?  Is it when the STDIN stream ends, or does `cat` receive a signal? In my case, the producer process receives a SIGINT and then exits with code 1, so how can `cat` (consumer process) know which exit code the producer process exited with?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`cat` doesn't know about `echo`'s signals. It receives end-of-file condition per [man pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html):

> If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have
>          been closed, then an attempt to read(2) from the pipe will see end-
>          of-file (read(2) will return 0).

For writers to the pipe, however, there is SIGPIPE. See the same man page

Comment: Is there a way to trap (or listen for) the end-of-file condition in the consumer?

Comment: Also, is there any way for the consumer to know the exit code of the producer process?

Comment: @AlexanderMills For the first, absolutely; if you're writing in C, you can call `feof(STDIN)` or whatever. For the second, no; only the process's parent knows its exit code.

Comment: @AlexanderMills  Draconis already addressed end-of-file part, but as far as exit code goes the best answer here is probably "not with simple shell pipe". If it's a pipeline created via C or Python code, in theory you could have both producer and consumer share a resource and write exit code to it. But of course that means both producer and consumer code are under your direct control. Maybe something like this would work `(echo "I'm a producer"; echo $? ) | some_consumer.py` but that implies consumer has to always check last line for a numeric string and handle cases when it's not.